Total derivative of a vector field as experienced by a moving particle
Consider a region of 3D space where there exists a continuous and differentiable vector field:
$$
\vec{A}=\left[A_1(x,y,z,t),A_2(x,y,z,t),A_3(x,y,z,t)\right]
$$
In that region of space there is a particle moving with velocity:
$$
\vec{v}=\left[v_1(x,y,z,t),v_2(x,y,z,t),v_3(x,y,z,t)\right]
$$
My question is: What is the total time derivative of the vector field as experienced by the particle?
If instead of a vector field we had a scalar field:
$$
S=S(x,y,z,t)
$$
Its total derivative as experienced by the particle I believe would be given by:
$$
\frac{dS}{dt}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}+\left(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{\nabla} \right)S
$$
However, in the case of a vector field, I am not sure of how to write the total derivative. My attempt so far is:
$$
\frac{d\vec{A}}{dt}=\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}+\left(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{\nabla} \right)\vec{A}+\left(\vec{A} \cdot \vec{\nabla} \right)\vec{v}+\left(\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{v} \right)\vec{A}
$$
Am I right? Am I missing any terms? Did I write any extra term that should not be there?
Note for context: The reason I am asking is because I do not understand why Maxwell's equations contain only partial time derivatives instead of total ones, since a particle would not know if the change of the field it is experiencing is due to the actual change of the field or due to moving in a region where the field changes spatially. I have the intuition that Lorentz's force and even magnetic fields might arise naturally just by considering total time derivatives. However, after asking some physicists, they don't tend to have the detailed knowledge on how to take the total time derivative of a vector field. I am an example of this, being a physicist and not knowing how to do this, so perhaps there is some mathematician out there who could shed some light.
Thank you very much in advance!

I know this seems crazy, but I'm going to write this out with unambiguous notation.
We have
$$
A: \mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R^3: (x, y, z, t) \mapsto (A_1(x, y, z, t), 
A_2(x, y, z, t), A_3(x, y, z, t))
$$
so that each $A_i$ is a function from $\mathbb R^4$ to $\mathbb R$.
We also have a path
$$
u: [a, b] \to \mathbb R^3: t \to (u_1(t), u_2(t), u_3(t))
$$
and we define
$$
v(t) = u'(t) = (u_1'(t), u_2'(t), u_3'(t))
$$
That is to say, $v$ is the velocity vector of some particular path, and I'm calling the parameterization of that path $u$.
We can look at the composite function
$$
F: [a, b] \to \mathbb R^3 : t \mapsto A(u_1(t), u_2(t), u_3(t), t)
$$
so that $F(t)$ is "the vector field $A$ at position $u(t)$, at time $t$."
Fortunately, $F$ is a function of one variable, and we can compute $F'(t)$ using the chain rule:
\begin{align}
F'(t) = & D_1A(u_1(t), u_2(t), u_3(t), t)  u_1'(t) + \\
        &D_2A(u_1(t), u_2(t), u_3(t), t)  u_2'(t) + \\
        &D_3A(u_1(t), u_2(t), u_3(t), t)  u_3'(t) + \\
        &D_4A(u_1(t), u_2(t), u_3(t), t) t'  
\end{align}
where $D_1A$ indicates the derivative of $A$ with respect to its first argument. A physicist, or Leibniz, might write this
$$
\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}
$$
but I'm not gonna do that.
We can simplify our expression for $F'(t)$ a bit, because $u_i'(t) = v_i(t)$, for instance, and $t' = 1$. So we get
\begin{align}
F'(t) = &D_1A(u_1(t), u_2(t), u_3(t), t)  v_1(t) + \\
        &D_2A(u_1(t), u_2(t), u_3(t), t)  v_2(t) + \\
        &D_3A(u_1(t), u_2(t), u_3(t), t)  v_3(t) + \\
        &D_4A(u_1(t), u_2(t), u_3(t), t)   
\end{align}
I suppose that in physics world, that's something like
$$
(v \cdot \nabla) A + \frac{\partial A}{\partial t},
$$
but it makes my eyes bleed to write that, especially that last term.

Thank you for bearing with my bad notation! Your answer is indeed the total derivative, but I was looking for the result from the perspective of the particle. If the vector field is constant, A(x,y,z,t)=C; and the trajectory is circular: u(t)=(Rcos(wt),Rsin(wt),0), according to your answer, the derivative would be null; while in reality the particle sees the vector field as constantly changing direction. I am looking for the way to capture that change, that is why I added the extra terms that I was trying to check, Thanks in advance!

@Alberto: The problem is that you want to capture that "apparent" change in direction (or perhaps "body-centered change in direction"), but you need some coordinate frame in which to represent it. After all, in the $xyz$-coordinate frame, the vector field is NOT changing (which is exactly what my computation shows). But for your curve (or moving point), you don't have an adapted time-changing coordinate frame...only a tangent vector. You need two more vectors to get a coordinate frame. If you know that your curve's second derivative is never zero, you can use the Frenet frame, but ...

...I think you'll find that generally unsatisfactory. I guess the question you need to ask yourself is "in this example, what answer would I like to get?" If you can't come up with that yourself for this simple an example, then there's probably no hope for a general answer.

thank you for replying again. The correct experimental result is obtained when I apply the last equation of my original post. However, I am unable to grasp its significance or its implications. Is this the same as the Lie derivative? I took the idea from this text:
https://www.jamespaulwesley.org/Document_Files/A_theorem_and_proof_for_the_total_time_derivative_of_a_vector_field_as_seen_by_a_moving_point.pdf
Warning: there is a typo in the very first equation of the linked paper. The last term, (v nabla) v, should be instead (A nabla) v, according to the author himself.
